# Detect from admin which model creates and assigns a foreign key

Tags: python, django

There are 3 main models: `Animal`, `Robot`, `Man`. Each has a foreign key on the `Photo` model. In the `Photo` model I'm overriding the `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` method.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
    is_alive = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if #main_model# == 'Robot':
           self.is_alive = False
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Robot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Human(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I'm filling any of main models from admin, I'm creating a photo that will be assigned to model (that I'm filling) as foreign key immediately after creating. How can I know from the `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` method, which of the main models is now creating?

[screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjFAh.png)

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ueh6.png)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if #main_model# == 'Robot':
       self.is_alive = False
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or, maybe, there are some other ways to do it? Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By using a `ForeignKey`, there are here thus three *one-to-many* relations with `Photo`, it thus means that a `Photo` can have zero or more `Animal`s, `Robot`s and `Human`s, and thus for example two humans, one animal and three robots all link to the same photo. Therefore I think it does not make much sense to perform this check.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have edited my post, but the question is not in checking. I want to update model on-the-fly (or, to be more accurate, before it will be written to the database).

Comment: Assuming your main model means instance of Photo model class, try with print(self). It should give you the current instance in question.

Comment: @RyuCoder: with `main_model`, the OP means "the" model `Robot`, `Animal`, `Human` that is referring to this `Photo` object.

Comment: Got it. As the main model instance wont be created until the saving to db is completed, you cant use the reverse relation concept here.

Comment: How are you creating this photo? Is it being done automatically, or just in an inline admin form? Show the code that does this.

Comment: The solution to op's question is - override the form_valid() method in the CreateView Class Based View. If you are using function based view, same logic could be used to update after the line if form.is_valid(): #whatever checking or updating needs to be done.

Comment: Daniel is right, actual code of the view that is doing this would be helpful

Comment: @DanielRoseman just in an inline admin form

Comment: Isn't this a flawed concept? Shouldn't the `is_alive` attribute be part of the non-Photo models? How can a photo be alive?

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform I agree, but this is just an example. The essence of the question remains the same. How can I know from the `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` method, which of the main models is now creating? Is it possible to get it in the parameters? Or, maybe there are ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot know whether the `Photo` belongs to a robit or not prior to saving the 'other partner' of the OneToOne, setting `is_alive = False` should happen after you have saved the `Robot` instance. In other words:

```
class Robot(BeepBoop):
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwarg)
        self.photo.is_alive = False
        self.photo.save()
```

This still leaves a problem when changing the 'owner' of a photo. Let's say a Robot's photo is swapped with a Man's photo. The Man's photo will have `is_alive = False` (since it belonged to a Robot before). 
Might be better to do this:

```
class Being(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, is_alive = True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.photo.is_alive = is_alive
        self.photo.save()

class Animal(Being):
    pass

class Man(Being):
    pass

class Robot(Being):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(is_alive = False, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need.